# Android - concatenate two videos

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I'm trying to concatenate two videos on Android. I'm already using ffmpeg for other needs, but I'm using [halfninja's one](https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264), which is only 0.9. The 0.9 one doesn't allow the following ways to do it:

```
// filter_complex isn't recognized
vk.run(new String[] {
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i",
        inputFile1,
        "-i",
        inputFile2,
        "-filter_complex",
        "'[0:1] [0:0] [1:1] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]'",
        "-map",
        "'[v]'",
        "-map",
        "'[a]'",
        outputFile
});

// Or, after converting the two videos to ts, trying to merge them: concat:file1.ts|file2.ts: No such file or directory
vk.run(new String[] {
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i",
        "'concat:" + ts1 + "|" + ts2 + "'",
        "-vcodec",
        "copy",
        "-acodec",
        "copy",
        "-absf",
        "aac_adtstoasc",
        output
});
```

The third thing I tried is to use the concat demuxer explained [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files), which isn't recognized with ffmpeg 0.9 either.

Is there any way to concatenate two videos on Android with ffmpeg 0.9 (or another library)?

Comment: try the 'faq' section 3.14. works on 0.9 on android 4.3 afaik.  http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-concatenate-video-files_003f

Comment: The concat protocol and concat demuxer aren't available in 0.9. I'll try the part explained in 3.14.4.

Comment: Correct 3.14.4 with special use of 'tail'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the only solution found was to use ffmpeg ≥1.1. I compiled the 2.1, it's working just fine. Here's what I use now:

```
/**
 * Concatenates two videos
 * @param inputFile1 First video file path
 * @param inputFile2 Second video file path
 * @param outputFile Output file path
 */
public static void concatenate(String inputFile1, String inputFile2, String outputFile) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Concatenating " + inputFile1 + " and " + inputFile2 + " to " + outputFile);
    String list = generateList(new String[] {inputFile1, inputFile2});
    Videokit vk = Videokit.getInstance();
    vk.run(new String[] {
            "ffmpeg",
            "-f",
            "concat",
            "-i",
            list,
            "-c",
            "copy",
            outputFile
    });
}

/**
 * Generate an ffmpeg file list
 * @param inputs Input files for ffmpeg
 * @return File path
 */
private static String generateList(String[] inputs) {
    File list;
    Writer writer = null;
    try {
        list = File.createTempFile("ffmpeg-list", ".txt");
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(list)));
        for (String input: inputs) {
            writer.write("file '" + input + "'\n");
            Log.d(TAG, "Writing to list file: file '" + input + "'");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "/";
    } finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Wrote list file to " + list.getAbsolutePath());
    return list.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: Hi Kernald ! Can you please share your ffmpeg file. I am having hard time getting this task done. After reading I tried since last 2 days to build new ffmpeg on windows following all I can find on internet. But so far I am not able to get it done. I will be highly thankful to you if you can share ffmpeg file with me so that I can execute same command in my project. Or please email directly to sourab.sharma13@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Sourab, I wrote a detailed how-to here: http://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/ I'll send you the files if you're still stuck after reading this, but it should works.

Comment: Thanks Kernald. I am trying that now. First I will try to learn how to fish, if still can't then will ask you to give a fish !!!

Comment: I have posted a comment on your blog. I am facing that error since yesterday. I extracted fresh NDK and ffmpeg folder this morning so that may be any temp files are not causing the error. And started doing as per your config file. Result is same. Please have a look at the comment on your blog, if that error seems familiar to you ?

Comment: I am following your code and it throws me an error of 12-16 19:49:57.416    5437-5437/? E/ffmpeg4android﹕ Command validation failed.
12-16 19:49:57.416    5437-5437/? E/ffmpeg4android﹕ Check if input file exists: /data/data/com.family45.golive.family45v1/cache/ffmpeg-list-1803386407.txt/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/dec24.mp4 /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/vid2.mp4.

Comment: @San You should open a new question showing your code and the full stack.

Comment: @Kernald, I did. Here's the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316705/unable-to-merge-videos-using-ffmpeg-commands. Help me out if you can.

Comment: Not worked!!  /data/user/0/app.user.videoeditor/cache/ffmpeg-list-2110086685.txt: Operation not permitted , failed command

Comment: I am getting Operation not permitted on .txt file.

Answer (score 2):

Marc's answer will work if your videos have the same encoding. I am using this for merging recorded videos in my app. When you record videos from both front camera and back camera it mixes audio (this maybe because of different frame rates between videos). So I am using following command, but it is much slower than merging with a list since it does not check encodings.

```
        final FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(activity);

        List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<>();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < videoFilenameList.size(); i++)
        {
            cmdList.add("-i");
            cmdList.add(videoFilenameList.get(i));

            sb.append("[").append(i).append(":0] [").append(i).append(":1]");
        }
        sb.append(" concat=n=").append(videoFilenameList.size()).append(":v=1:a=1 [v] [a]");
        cmdList.add("-filter_complex");
        cmdList.add(sb.toString());
        cmdList.add("-map");
        cmdList.add("[v]");
        cmdList.add("-map");
        cmdList.add("[a]");
        cmdList.add("-preset");
        cmdList.add("ultrafast");
        cmdList.add(outFile);

        sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String str : cmdList)
        {
            sb.append(str).append(" ");
        }

        String[] cmd = cmdList.toArray(new String[cmdList.size()]);

        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStart()
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: it was working last time I checked it and my application which contains this code block is still working. What error do you receive?

Comment: I  getting this error Error configuring complex filters Invalid argument

Comment: Can you please let me know one thing... file1 and file2 combine size if 14mb after joing these two file the size is 62mb?

Comment: its working on moto g if i add "-y" in start but when i test on tab it show me error  Error configuring complex filters Invalid argument

Comment: -y means override existing output file. So if there is an existing file with same name you need to add "-y". This tool does not compress well enough so file size increases, I could not solve it back then. I believe you have a problem with file paths, or maybe in tablet you try to access a path that you do not have permission.

Comment: i have add all permission.. if i select two same video for merging then this command working fine but if i merge two different video file then it show error i think due to different bitrate and frame size....how can i merge two video with different bitrate and framesize?

Comment: I used this code to merge videos captured from phone and helped me. You may need to do more search if your videos are too different from each other.