# Merge multiple videos using FFMPEG in android

Tags: android, merge, ffmpeg

I'm required to merge 'n' number of mp4 videos. For now I'm using ffmpeg library and achieved merging 2 videos using the following command:

```
  String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", input_video1,
                            "-i", input_video2, "-strict", "experimental",
                            "-filter_complex",
                            "[0:v]scale=hd720,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=hd720,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
                            "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "hd720", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", get_br + "k", merged_video_op_path};
```

But how can I do it for n videos. Is there any command to do it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could possibly script it, but you must explicitly tell the concat filter how many inputs there are.

Comment: Okay can you please give an example?

Comment: Achieved this for n videos by following this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325615/android-concatenate-two-videos

Comment: That answer appears to concatenate 2 inputs, but I assumed you wanted to concatenate any arbitrary number of inputs.

Comment: Check generateList method. We can send any number of input files to it