# Merge views with an existing video

Tags: java, android, android-layout, video

I want to merge a view with an already existing video and get a video out of it. An example would be, adding a text with a `Textview` on a video. This functionality can be seen by many social media apps like tik tok and instagram.

How are they doing that, someone got an idea? Currently I just have a `Textview` and a `ScalableVideoView` overlayed, but Idk how to merge them into an video.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20358243/7649582

Answer (score 6):

I think that you can achieve that using "ffmpeg" to generate a new video using an image/video overlay.

Check this post talking about this tool:[ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/12111/26084)

If you want to use ffmpeg on Android follow this link to build and call it from Android with JNI: [ffmpeg on Android](https://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/)

source of ffmpeg: [source](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg)

Hope it helps.

Comment: how would it look like, when i add multiple texts ?

Comment: Hi @AhmetKazaman you can use multiple images in intervals like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42945032/2493852

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, that you can use ffmpeg to create the image file, too (see end of posting):

[create text video/image with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710099/ffmpeg-create-blank-screen-with-text-video)

Conclusion: As far as i know, you need to do it in two steps (Example under windows):

```
ffmpeg.exe -f lavfi -i color=c=black@0.0:s=640x480,format=rgba -vf "drawtext=fontfile="C\\:/Windows/fonts/arialbd.ttf":fontsize=72:fontcolor='white':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text='Stack Overflow'" -frames:v 1 overlay.png
ffmpeg.exe -i inputvideo.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```